# Is it possible to read all rows of Cassandra partition in one Spark worker?

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, spark-cassandra-connector, zipkin

I am trying to optimize [Zipkin Dependencies Spark job](https://github.com/openzipkin/zipkin-dependencies-spark/blob/master/cassandra/src/main/scala/io/zipkin/dependencies/spark/cassandra/ZipkinDependenciesJob.scala) to run in fewer stages by minimizing the number of `reduceByKey` steps it does. The data is read from the following table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS zipkin.traces (
    trace_id  bigint,
    ts        timestamp,
    span_name text,
    span      blob,
    PRIMARY KEY (trace_id, ts, span_name)
)
```

There, a single partition `trace_id` contains a complete trace, and contains anywhere from a few to a few hundred rows. However, that whole partition is converted by the Spark job into very simple `RDD[((String, String), Long)]`, reducing the number of entries from billions to just a few hundreds.

Unfortunately, the current code is doing it by reading all rows independently via

```
sc.cassandraTable(keyspace, "traces")
```

and using two `reduceByKey` steps to come up with `RDD[((String, String), Long)]`.  If there was a way to read the whole partition in one go, in one Spark worker process, and process it all in memory, it would be a huge speed improvement, eliminating the need to store/stream huge data sets coming out of the current first stages.

-- edit --

To clarify, the job must read *all data* from the table, billions of partitions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key to keeping all partition data on the same spark worker without doing a shuffle is to use `spanByKey`

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key

```
CREATE TABLE events (year int, month int, ts timestamp, data varchar, PRIMARY KEY (year,month,ts));

sc.cassandraTable("test", "events")
  .spanBy(row => (row.getInt("year"), row.getInt("month")))

sc.cassandraTable("test", "events")
  .keyBy(row => (row.getInt("year"), row.getInt("month")))
  .spanByKey
```

If there is no shuffle than all of the modifications will be done in place and pipelined together as an iterator.

Make sure to note the caveat:

> Note: This only works for sequentially ordered data. Because data is
>   ordered in Cassandra by the clustering keys, all viable spans must
>   follow the natural clustering key order.

Comment: I was the one who left the comments :-)

Comment: but the Spark job is expected to read *all* partitions, so this approach does not work.

Comment: ah, perhaps you want to do a spanByKey? Basically if you avoid the shuffle with the ReduceByKey you should be ok.

https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/edba853b9630f60de2b3f1b0db2118792a5a5a89/spark-cassandra-connector/src/main/scala/com/datastax/spark/connector/PairRDDFunctions.scala

Comment: Thanks, @RussS, that's exactly what I was looking for. If you want to edit your answer, I can accept it.

Here's the docs reference: https://github.com/datastax/spark-cassandra-connector/blob/master/doc/3_selection.md#grouping-rows-by-partition-key